# jQuery and JOOMLA

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla1.5

I was making a Joomla template (1.5 don't ask why ~.~) and I will use some thing like this:

```js
$('.linkseffect').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '180px'
    }, 300);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: '68px'
    }, 300);
});
```

```css
.linkseffect {
    background:#CCC;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border: 6px #f7f7f7 solid;
    width:68px;
    height:61px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:3px;
    display;block;
}
img {
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.text {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #222;
    text-shadow: 1px 0px 0px #fff;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
    <a><div class="linkseffect"><img src="http://im36.gulfup.com/VhCD4.png" /><div class="text">Directory of               <br /> Experts and blah </div></div></a>
    <a><div class="linkseffect"><img src="http://im36.gulfup.com/YSGsJ.png" style="margin-top:7px; margin-right:5px;" /><div class="text">blah of <br /> blah blah blah</div></div></a>
    <a><div class="linkseffect"><img src="http://im36.gulfup.com/jkQbz.png" /><div class="text">regester for <br /> blah blah blah</div></div></a>
</div>
```

I integrated jQuery to the template and the script through extensions and codes etc
I put the js code of the example above in separated file and linked it to the `index.php` with the normal way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/spc/js/links.js"></script>
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: `joomla template (1.5 don't ask why~_~)`. I think my name has never been more relevant than at this moment.

Comment: It might be possible due to Jquery conflict. Please use jQuery.noConflict.

Comment: OT but make sure you have updated with the hotfix released yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding javascript and css like in here [adding javascript](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript)

Joomla is using mootools, so it could be issue between jquery and mootools, check it through the firebug and add [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: var j = jQuery.noConflict(); and use variable j instead of $ to manipulate with jquery.